# Pit as a past tense verb

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

> The violence **pit** pro-Russian separatists against Ukrainian forces and those who support the government in Kiev.

A friend of mine says **pit** is used as a past tense verb in this sentence. What is the present tense form of **pit**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of usage differing in Britain and the USA. For some reason, most Americans don't change the verb form for the past tense of certain short verbs ending in *-it*. So *fit, spit, shit, slit* and *pit* are thus formed both in the present and the past tense as far as Americans are concerned, whereas people from Britain would almost always use *fitted, spat, shat, slitted* and *pitted* for the past tense. However, even in Britain *hit, split* and *quit* follow the American pattern (though *quitted* is also used); and Americans do say *sat* rather than *sit*.

Comment: *Fitted* and *pitted* have their uses in American English; for example, *The suit fit him last year* but *The tailor fitted him for a suit last year*, and if making a pie, I will have *pitted* cherries all afternoon. As for *spit* and *shit*, you'll often hear *spat* and *shat* as past forms.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is correct that *pit* is being used as a past tense in the example, but by most standards it is being used incorrectly. Dictionaries (e.g. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pit)) mostly say that the verb is *pit*, and the past tense is *pitted*. It is clear that the past tense is intended, (the present tense would be *pits*), and there certainly are those who think *pit*, used transitively, retains its irregular past *pit*; but the word itself is so rare that it is being regularized by sheer unfamiliarity.

Comment: Was *pit* ever the irregular past tense of *pit*, or is it just an infrequently-used past tense formed by analogy with *hit, quit, spit, split* and so forth? I'd guess the latter. The OED says nothing about *pit* having an irregular past tense, and the past tense citations it gives all have *pitted*. It's a verb being *unregularized* by sheer unfamiliarity.